# Executing some SQL code in a failed transaction

Tags: sqlite, transactions, cherrypy, peewee

In my CherryPy + Peewee app I often use the following pattern: start a transaction, perform a list of operations and return a page that shows the result. If something goes wrong during any of the operations, I add a row to a logging table, then redirect to a page that shows that row.

The problem is that the redirection in CherryPy is performed by raising an exception, and the exception causes a few transactions to rollback. The rollback is what I need for the operation that failed (and all the previous operations even if they succeeded), but it is not what I want for the logging.

For example with the following code if the user goes to `a_page?a=1&b=2&c=3`:

- `do_this` will find `x != y` and not execute `show_message`
- `do_this` will update one record on `Table1`
- `do_that` will find `x == y` and execute `show_message`
- `show_message` will add one row to the `Message` log table
- `show_message` will raise an exception in order to redirect to a page that will show the message just logged

Since an exception has been risen while in a transaction, both the update on `Table1` made in `do_this` and the message logged in `show_message` will be rolled back.

How to I commit the rows in the logging table and rollback all the other changes?

```
@cherrypy.expose
def a_page(self, a, b, c):
    with db.transaction():
        self.do_this(a, b)
        self.do_that(b, c)
    return render('it_worked.html')

def do_this(self, x, y):
    if x == y:
        self.show_message('Wrong this')
    Table1.update(f2=x).where(f1 == y).execute()

def do_that(self, x, y):
    if x != y:
        self.show_message('Wrong that')
    Table1.update(f3=x).where(f1 == z).execute()

def show_message(self, message)
    msg = Message.create(msg=message)
    raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('show_message?id={}'.format(msg.id))
```

Comment: Probably nested transactions, i.e. savepoints.

Comment: @CL. As far as I know nested transactions allow you not to save the inner operations. I need the opposite: I don't want to save transactions executed until now, but I want to save the very last one.

Comment: I found a solution that I don't like because (1) it requires the transaction to be passed to the function and (2) will not work if there are nested transactions. It's in my answer below. Please let me know if that's a good solution or I can do better

Comment: You'd have to write the log after rolling back to the savepoint.

Comment: @CL. That's what I did in the example below. `Log.show_log()` needs to know the outermost transaction in order to roll it back, and I don't know if I like that yet.

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to work, but I don't like because it requires passing the transaction down to the function, and because it might (not sure yet) not work with nested transactions.

```
import cherrypy
import peewee

db = peewee.SqliteDatabase('test.db', threadlocals=True)

class PeeweeModel(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Table1(PeeweeModel):
    field1 = peewee.CharField()

Table1.drop_table(True)
Table1.create_table(True)

class Log(PeeweeModel):
    msg = peewee.CharField()

    @staticmethod
    def show_log(msg, txn):
        txn.rollback()
        msg = Log.create(msg=msg)
        txn.commit()
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('show_log?msg_id={}'.format(msg.id))

Log.drop_table(True)
Log.create_table(True)

def table_content():
    return '<br>'.join(['{} {}'.format(row.id, row.field1) for row in Table1.select()])

html = """<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="index">index</a><br>
<a href="add_row">add_row</a><br>
{}<br>
Table1<br>
{}<br>
</body>
</html>"""

class App():

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, msg='Hello'):
        return html.format(msg, table_content())

    @cherrypy.expose
    def add_row(self):
        with db.transaction() as txn:
            Table1.update(field1=Table1.field1 + 1).execute()
            Table1.update(field1=Table1.field1 + 1).where(Table1.id == 2).execute()
            if Table1.select().count() == 5:
                raise Log.show_log('Something went wrong', txn)
            Table1.create(field1=1, field2=2)
        return html.format('Added record to Table1', table_content())

    @cherrypy.expose
    def show_log(self, msg_id):
        msg = Log.get(Log.id == msg_id)
        text = 'Message id {}: {}'.format(msg.id, msg.msg)
        return html.format(text, table_content())

cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/')
```